# JBoss - server.xml connector not properly configurated for certificate recognition

Tags: security, ssl, configuration, jboss, ssl-certificate

I've obtained a trial root certificate from verisign (valid for 15 days, more or less), and imported it to a keystore created by jdk keytool. All the steps required, i.e. the creation of csr to obtain a certificate (which is not self-signed) and so on were issued.

These are the files the keystore contains:

- private key
- a trial root certificate obtained by verisgin
- my own certificate created by a csr and obtained from verising

Regretably, the data returned by firefox is the one corresponding to the private key included in the keystore when the last was created.

I suspect there is something to do with the CN of the certificate created from csr, probably that piece of data should contain the FQDN of the hosts which runs the application. I'm using JBoss 4.x as the app. server and configured server.xml Connector element, the so called configuration is the following:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    redirectPort="8443"
    maxThreads="3000" scheme="https" secure="true"
    strategy="ms"
    address="${jboss.bind.address}"
    keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/t2facebook.jks"
    keystorePass="TPC.961"
truststoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/t2facebook.jks"
    truststorePass="TPC.961"
    sslProtocol="TLS"
clientAuth="true"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: By the way, the error I'm getting from firefox is: sec_error_ca_cert_invalid

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I was importing the certificate with a different alias from the private key one. Just import the certificate (or the chain or certificates, I mean root, intermediate and the one obtained from csr) under the same alias of the private key and will work fine.